# Why do so many pollutants affect the estrogen receptor?

Tags: human-biology, endocrinology, environment

We make loads of chemicals, and release them into the environment for reasons.  We have loads of hormone receptors.

There are many instances of human made chemicals affecting the estrogen receptor, [currently in particular hair straightening chemicals associated with higher uterine cancer risk](https://www.nih.gov/news-events/news-releases/hair-straightening-chemicals-associated-higher-uterine-cancer-risk), and also in other areas of the internet that I am loath to link to.  I can think of no other hormone or neurotransmitter receptor in the human body that is affected by so many human made chemicals, at least if one follows the media.

Why is the estrogen receptor affected  by so many human made chemicals, and other hormone receptors apparently not?

Answer (score -1):

Probably, many other endocrine receptors also get functionally disrupted by small molecules people manufacture. I think there's a dearth of research studies designed to find them. So, many molecules disrupt the estrogen receptor because researchers are biased by [the Streetlight Effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streetlight_effect). **The absence of evidence for disruption of other endocrine receptor functions is likely insignificant.**

Sexual development is probably an endocrinological "canary in the coal mine" rather than being more sensitive to exogenous small molecules than other endocrine contexts. The estrogen receptor gets its pathophysiology described so extensively because of the way teratogens are characterized; medical scientists are experienced with studying the developing fetuses of lab animals, and perturbed sexual development is measurable with widely known correlates (like [anogenital distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anogenital_distance)) that work as popular response variables.

Once a hypothesis is generated, say that *molecule A disrupts development by binding to a sex hormone receptor*, then followup experiments lead to experiments where binding affinities get measured. So by *directly incubating molecule A and a receptor,* a binding affinity gets measured. But this is rarely done in the presence of competing ligands or receptors.

Looking for references to explain this, it's difficult because it's a kind of subtle background truth about experimental designs. Here's a quote from a paper that quotes a bunch of other papers (albeit in a different context of protein:protein binding):

> [H]igh affinity does not guarantee high specificity, which is controlled by either partner binding to other proteins discriminatively (Bolon et al., 2005; Grigoryan et al., 2009; Havranek et al., 2003; Janin, 1995; Kortemme et al., 2004; Shifman and Mayo, 2003). [Paper on specificity in protein:protein interactions](https://doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btt121)

So, for example, all the 'estrogen analogs' that are measured to bind to an estrogen receptor also have affinities for an androgen receptor, an opiod receptor and a glass surface, but it's simply not the usual research practice to characterize a wide range of affinities. Imagine the technical requirements of an experiment of, say, studying the competitive binding of a mixture of estrogen, cholesterol, and porphyrin binding estrogen receptor, let alone a competitive mixture of receptors.

If a ligand does bind well to a receptor, people tend to assume it does so specifically and (patho)functionally but this is oversimplified.